# How to animate search box on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, animation

I've create search box with search button, but i want the search box to be visible only when i click on search button with animation (toggle or something...) like http://prntscr.com/tijo4 , website: http://thenextweb.com/.

I have tried only this : http://jsfiddle.net/JHdzd

HTML:

```
    <div id="search">
        <input title="Search for..." id="forsearch" type="text" class="forsearch_products">
        <input class="search-button" type="submit" value="Search">
    </div>
```

css:

```
#search {
    width: 250px;
    height: 28px;
    background-color: #C7D7E8;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 0px;
}

input#forsearch.forsearch_products {
    width: 135px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 2px solid #6B9DD3;
    margin: 0 3px 0 8px;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
}

input.search-button {
    width: 85px;
    height: 28px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background: rgb(237,173,113); 
}
```

Comment: If you are doing this in native JavaScript, then the `setInterval` function is something you should look into. If you can use a library like jQuery/Dojo/MooTools/etc., this problem becomes trivial.

Comment: @Default i use jQuery on the site but am not very familiar doing custom js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, this is very simple. Using this code will fade in your search box (which I have adjusted to be initially hidden) upon the click of your search button:

```
$("#search").click(function(){
    $("#forsearch").fadeIn(1000);
})
```

[Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JHdzd/1/) to see it in action. I have also adjusted your search box's position to be fixed to the right (you can see why if you remove my style changes, but leave the search box as hidden initially). You can also [check out this page](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) to learn more about jQuery Effects.

Comment: That would submit the form before the user could even type in it.

Comment: @j08691 I realize this, but Mirko requested in the question for the search box to be visible _after_ the search button is clicked. There are many ways he can hook it up so the form is submitted differently. Not arguing it is the best idea, just addressing the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="search"] {
     background: url("http://www.dreamtemplate.com/dreamcodes/web_icons/gray-classic-search-icon.png") no-repeat scroll 5px 50% #ffffff;
     border-radius: 4px;
     border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
     color: transparent;
     cursor: pointer;
     font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
     font-size: 14px;
     padding: 12px 5px 12px 22px;
     transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
     width: 22px;
}
```

see the demo http://cssdesk.com/Gsedv